# OCaml sorting list of user-defined types

Tags: list, sorting, types, ocaml

I have a list of **cache** and I need to sort it by *hiddenDate* e.g. "2007/07/20" (most recently first). How do I sort this list in Ocaml using only the hiddenDate parameter?

```
type cache = {         
    code: string;      
    name: string;      
    state: string;      
    (...)
    hiddenDate: string; 
    (...) 
    altitude: int       
} ;;

val hiddenDateSort: cache list -> cache list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation for the [sort](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) function:

```
val sort : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

> Sort a list in
>   increasing order according to a comparison function. The comparison
>   function must return 0 if its arguments compare as equal, a positive
>   integer if the first is greater, and a negative integer if the first
>   is smaller (see Array.sort for a complete specification). For example,
>   compare is a suitable comparison function. The resulting list is
>   sorted in increasing order. List.sort is guaranteed to run in constant
>   heap space (in addition to the size of the result list) and
>   logarithmic stack space. The current implementation uses Merge Sort.
>   It runs in constant heap space and logarithmic stack space.

So, you need to provide a comparison function for hidden date field. Moreover, you can't just compare dates like strings. This will lead to incorrect ordering. The first approximation would be the following:

```
let date str = Str.(split (regexp "/") str)
let compare_dates s1 s2 = compare (date s1) (date s2)
let compare_by_hidden_date c1 c2 = compare_dates c1.hiddenDate c2.hiddenDate
let sort_by_hidden_date = List.sort compare_by_hidden_date
```

Comment: Given that the dates are in a fixed-size, most significant first format, comparing the strings is fine.

Comment: @Gilles yes, and since this is ISO date, I would suggest writing it in some  ISO format like 2007-07-20